# kernel32.GetDateFormatEx and ar-SA dates

Tags: windows, date, winapi, calendar, locale

I am using `GetDateFormatEx` (more specifically, `ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetDateFormatEx` using Python), which is documented at

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

And using today's date as the `SYSTEMTIME` input, and a `NULL` format string and 0 flags. however specifically for the `ar-SA` locale.

It is returning a value of `"06/01/37"`, which is not what I expected.  I expected to be in the `ar-SA` language (ie, what, in my English eyes, look like squibbles).

I also expected it would return an arabic short date string, specifically, for the gregorian calendar, however it seems to be using the Hijri calendar instead.  How do I detect that a Hijri calendar is being used?

So, to re-iterate, what I want to know is:

1. How do I get the arabic date, something more like: تشرين الأول أكتوبر ١٩ ١٥
2. How do I detect the type of calendar that the user is expecting to be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you yourself has overridden the locale settings for date formatting on your testing PC? Maybe you need to use the [`LOCALE_NOUSEROVERRIDE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373821%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag.

**UPDATE**

I have tested this in C++

```cpp
GetDateFormatEx(L"ar-SA", LOCALE_NOUSEROVERRIDE | DATE_AUTOLAYOUT | DATE_LONGDATE, nullptr, nullptr, buf, _countof(buf), nullptr);
```

The resulting date is

> ‏06/‏محرم/‏1437

**UPDATE 2**

This apparently depends on how Windows define the locale. I have tried different combination of the flags (`DATE_AUTOLAYOUT | DATE_LONGDATE`, `DATE_AUTOLAYOUT | DATE_USE_ALT_CALENDAR | DATE_LONGDATE`, `DATE_AUTOLAYOUT | DATE_USE_ALT_CALENDAR`). While for `"ar-SA"` this gives

> ‏06/‏محرم/‏1437
>
> ‏06/‏01/‏1437
>
> ‏06/‏01/‏37

for `"ja-JP"` (Japanese) it gives

> 2015‎年‎10‎月‎19‎日
>
> 平成 ‎27‎年‎10‎月‎19‎日
>
> 平成 ‎27/‎10/‎19

I suspect (not knowing full Windows NLS capabilities), you will have to use either specific formatting string or some other library, like ICU, to get more squigly dates.

**UPDATE 3**

It probably does not get any more squigly than with `DATE_AUTOLAYOUT | DATE_USE_ALT_CALENDAR` flags and `L"dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy gg"` format:

> ‏الإثنين, ‏06 ‏محرم, ‏1437 ‏بعد الهجرة

**UPDATE 4**

Further search reveals [this](https://www.microsoft.com/middleeast/msdn/ArabicCalendar.aspx#NLSAPI):

> **Note:** If you got the Gregorian date with Arabic names, then you probably forgot to set the calendar type to the Hijri calendar.

So it seems your Windows would have to have the Hijri calendar selected in your locale for the numbers to get formatted with the traditional numerals.

**UPDATE 5**

> Finally, how do I detect that the Hijri calendar is being used in that case?

You can detect the calendar that is in use by calling [`GetLocaleInfoEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318103.aspx) with `LOCALE_ICALENDARTYPE` as its `LCType` parameter and comparing the returned number with constants defined in `WinNls.h`:

```
#define CAL_HIJRI                      6      // Hijri (Arabic Lunar) calendar
#define CAL_UMALQURA                   23     // UmAlQura Hijri (Arabic Lunar) calendar
```

Comment: However, I still see recognisable numbers there.  if you look at the win32 clock, you won't see those.  I also actually _want_ the user-specified date, and I'm testing on my dev machine that has the date format set and I want to get a similar output as the clock.  Finally, how do I detect that the Hijri calendar is being used in that case?

Comment: @Arafangion: Since you have initially mentioned Python, what about using OS independent locale stuff provider like PyICU? It is an option at least worth considering.

Comment: I already use unicode, and have good unicode support, however I could've sworn that ICU only provided unicode encoding services - I had no idea it also provides date handling and (apparently) calendar services - thanks for checking it out.

Comment: You've very well answered my question, in _addition_ to providing me with more resources.